# How not to lose the asynchronous call?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework

How not to lose the asynchronous call `anotherService.doSomething(res)` ? Otherwise I'm not sure the piece of code will execute.

```
    myDAO.update(param).map { // update() returns Future[Option[Object]]
      case Some(row) =>
        if (row.active) {
          myDAO.selectUser(size).map { //selectUser() returns Future[Option[User]]
            case Some(res) =>
              anotherService.doSomething(res) //doSomething() returns Future[StandaloneWSResponse] but this line might not run without being able to keep track. This is my problem
            case _ => Left(Wrong)
          }
        }
        Right(...)
      case None => Left(Wrong)
    }
  }
```

My idea is to store the result of the if and doing something like this:

```
val v = if (row.active) {
          myDAO.selectUser(size).map { //selectUser() returns Future[Option[User]]
            case Some(res) =>
              anotherService.doSomething(res) //doSomething() returns Future[StandaloneWSResponse]
            case _ => Left(Wrong)
          }
Future.successful(v)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "lose" the call? which piece of code (line?) are you thinking might not execute? Also, what is the type returned by `mySelect(...)`? Future?

Comment: Yes exactly this line `anotherService.doSomething(res)` might not run without being able to keep track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a for-comprehension is more idiomatic, you just need to provide a value for each None:

```
for {
  rowOpt <- myDAO.selectUser(size)
  userOpt <- rowOpt.filter(_.active).fold(Future.successful(Option.empty[...])) {row =>
    myDAO.selectUser(size)
  }
  resultOpt <- userOpt.fold(Future.succesful(Option.empty[...])) {user =>
    anotherService.doSomething(res)
  }
} yield resultOpt.toEither(Wrong)
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scalaz and for-comprehension to make sure what is that did not work there.

```
import scalaz._
val result = for {
  updateObjResultOpt <- myDAO.update(param).toRightDisjunction("error when Update")
  if(updateObjReesurtOpt.filter(_.active).nonEmpty)
  userOptional <- myDAO.selectUser(size).toRightDisjunction("error when select user")
  if(userOptional.nonEmpty)
  otherResult <- anotherService.doSomething(res).toRightDisjunction("error when execute doSomething")
} yield otherResult

// if you want return Future[ValidationNel[String, StandaloneWSResponse]]
val validationNelResult = result.fold(error => Failure(NonEmptyList(error)), otherResult => Success(otherResult)) 

// if you want to return the Future[result], you can use pattern matching 
val futureResult = validationNelResult.match {
    case Success(data) => Ok("success")
    case Failure(error) => BadRequest(error)
    case _ => BadRequest("other error")
}
```

I have not compiled it yet but I think it will working...